# Can not add JDK and JRE Path for Windows 10 (64-bit)

Tags: windows-10, 64-bit, java, environment-variables, path

I have installed `Java SE` and when I try to enter the path in environment variable, it does not take it. 
I have the following,
[image]

According to this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wp6uS7CmivE), both `JDK` and `JRE` bin paths were added manually. Since I have Windows 10 updated version, my `edit environment variables` looks like above and I tried to add paths as indicated in the picture above.

As shown in the video I tried to add both JDK and JRE's bin directory with `;`, it does not take it.

How can I do this? Any suggestions would be appreciated.

(I am installing `Java` for the first time)

Comment: From the look of  the dialog you have to add a line per path component, instead of adding it to some existing line.

Comment: @xenoid okay, I'll try that. one quick confirmation, should I add the whole path (8 panels or boxex with C:Program Data\Oracle...) or just the bin path?

Comment: Just the `bin` path I think.

Answer (score 1):

After suggestion in comment section, I created a new path under `System variables` in Environment Variables with JDK and JRE bin paths. This worked well.

However, after spending little more time, I found that when I clicked `Edit text...` button with very first cell selected as in the picture above, I was able to edit the path. Before that, I was trying to click on `edit` that did not take the path variable and does not edit path.

So, the solution should be to click on `Edit text...` button while the first cell selected would allow you to edit path. (This will eliminate the need to create new path)

Answer (score -1):

To add Java JRE and JDK paths, you need to add the `bin` directory as that is where the java binaries are located. `Java` itself should work but usually for JDK you have to add it yourself. Here is a tutorial on how to add it to your path after the update.

https://javatutorial.net/set-java-home-windows-10

Comment: Link-only answers to a third-party website without providing the contents of the tutorial within your answer isn't all that helpful

Comment: how is it not helpful? The link tells you what to do... Its not that hard... Plus, you can find the same thing with a simple Google search. That isn't that hard either.

Comment: If it isn't difficult providing the information to in the answer body

Comment: i might as well take a screenshot of the page. Same thing. People are too dependent.

Comment: "The link tells you what to do" - But the answer doesn't contain that information.

Comment: thats why the link is there

Comment: Link-Only answers are frowned upon.  If that link stopped working today, then the information wouldn't be accessible, hence the reason the information should be quoted and cited in the body of the answer.  You can ask any SU moderator if link-only answers are acceptable and they will say pretty much the same thing.  There is more relevant information in the tutorial then your few sentences provided.  It isn't about how difficult it is to do, I don't need that tutorial to modify the system variable on my system, but other users do and that is who I care about.